# How to apply constraints on a number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I encountered the following question, which is a sample of similar questions.

> A restaurant has a fixed number of chairs. If they are set around tables with a capacity of 7 (divide them into groups of 7), no chair is left over. If they are set around tables with a capacity of 4, there are two chairs left over. If they are set around tables with a capacity of 3, one chair is left over. How many numbers smaller than 1000 are there for the capacity of the restaurant?

I know that the problem states the following relationships:

$n= 7k_1 = 4k_2+2=3k_3+1$

With try and error (examining the numbers divisible by 7) I could find $70$, but it is time-consuming. However, I have no strategy to put this problem in a mathematic formula, and how to find the remaining numbers.

Comment: You should refer to CRT for the existence of the solution/s mod(84)  and then you can solve using the relations you have found using modular arithmetic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly observe that the problem is equivalent to the following modular system

- $x\equiv 0 \pmod 7$
- $x\equiv 2 \pmod 4$
- $x\equiv 1 \pmod 3$

and the existence and uniqueness of the solution $\pmod{7\cdot4\cdot3}\,$ is guaranteed by [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

To solve we can observe that

- $x\equiv 0 \pmod 7 \implies x=7k$
- $x\equiv 2 \pmod 4\implies 3k\equiv 2 \pmod 4\implies -k=2+4h\implies x=14+28h$
- $x\equiv 1 \pmod 3\implies 2+h\equiv 1 \pmod 3 \implies h\equiv 2 \pmod 3\implies h=2+3s \\\implies x=70+84s$

Therefore all the solutions are

$$x=70, \,70+84,\, 70+2\cdot 84,...$$

More informally in this simple case we can also find $70$ by inspection as you did and then note that we can add up multiple factors $7\cdot4\cdot3=84$ to obtain others solution (in any case for the uniqueness we should always refer to CRT).

Comment: You wrote first $x = 7k$, then in the second line, you wrote $3k$ instead of x. Is it correct?

Comment: And I like the informal solution, considering that after I found a number for the first two equations, $7$ and $4$, then I can add up $7 . 4$ to test the resulting numbers against the third condition.

Comment: Yes since 7k =3k mod(4)

Comment: Alternative way is fine for thi simple case to find solutions, as noticed you need CRT to be sure that those are the unique solutions unless you don’t verify it for all n up to 1000.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the Chinese Remainder Theorem:

Notice;

$n = 7k_1 = 4k_2 + 2 = 3k_3 + 1$

We want to get rid of those $+2$ and $+1$ by adding or subtracting  multiples of $7$.  $1-7 = -6 = -2*3$ for example or $1 + 14 = 15= 5*3$

$n = 7k_1 = 4k_2 + 2 = 3k_3 - 6+7$

$n - 7 = 7(k_1-1) = 4k_2 - 5 = 3(k_3 -2)$

$n-7 = 7(k_1-1) = 4(k_2 -1) - 1 = 3(k_3 -2)$

Now we want to get rid of that $-1$ by adding or subtracting a multiple of $3*7 = 21$.  Example $-1 + 21 = 20 = 4*5$ or  ... gee... $-1 - 63 = -64 = -17*4$.

$n-7 = 7(k_1-1) = 4(k_2 -1)+20 - 21 = 3(k_3 -2)$

$n+14 = 7(k_1 -1)+21 = 4(k_2 -1) + 20 = 3(k_3 -2) + 21$

$n+14 = 7(k_1 +2) = 4(k_2 +4) = 3(k_3 + 5)$

This will work if $(k_1+2) = 3*4=12$ and $(k_2 + 4) = 7*3=21$ and $k_3 + 5 = 4*7=28$ and $n+14 = 7*3*4 = 84$

In other words if $k_1 =10; k_2 = 17; k_3 = 23$ and $n = 70 = 7*10 = 4*17+2 = 3*23 + 1$.

But ... it's easier to learn the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

=====

Alternatively we can do it through successive remainders.

$n = 3*4*7q + r=84q + r; 0\le r < 84$.

$r = 28p + s$ where $0\le s < 28$ and $0 \le p < 3$ but

$n = 7(12q + 4p) + s= 7k_1$ we know $7$ divides $s$ so $s= 0,7,14$.

But we also have

$n = 4(21q + 7p) + s = 4k_2 + 2$ so $s$ is two more than a multiple of $4$.  The only choices of $0,7,14$ that satisfy that is $s = 14$.  So $s = 14$

So $r = 28p + 14$ where $0\le p < 3$ so $r =14,42, $ or $70$.

But $n = 84q + r = 3*28q + r =3k_2 + 1$ so $r$ is one more than a multiple of $3$.  $r = 70$ is the only option that works.

So $n =84q + 70$.  It doesn't actually matter what $q$ is.  As $3,4,7$ all divide $84$ all $84q+70$ will have the same remainders when divided by $3,4,7$ so all of them are solutions.

But, really, just learn the Chinese Remainder Theorem.  You wont regret it.